# Missing Return Statement When Implementing the StubProvider Interface

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to implement the StubProvider Interface as Kevin Poorman does in his blog here: [Kevin's Month of Testing Blog - Part 3 of 3](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/05/month-of-testing-advanced-topics-in-salesforce-unit-testing-part-3-of-3.html) and on line 3 I am getting the error 'Missing return statement required return type: Object.' What could I possibly be doing wrong? Also, because we are in between releases, yes, I am in a sandbox that is running Summer '18, so it isn't (or, shouldn't be) the switch statement causing this issue. Ideas?

```
@isTest
public class AttachmentTriggerDisabledMockStub implements System.StubProvider {
    public Object handleMethodCall(Object stubbedObject, String stubbedMethodName,
                                   Type returnType, List<Type> listOfParamTypes, 
                                   List<String> listOfParamNames,
                                   List<Object> listOfArgs){
        switch on stubbedMethodName{
            when 'Disable_Attachment_AD__c', 'Disable_Attachment_AI__c', 'Disable_Attachment_AU__c'{
                return false;
            }      
        }                                        
    }    
}
```

Comment: why not use apexmocks (github)? -- much less work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a method has a non-`void` return type, you're responsible for ensuring that all code paths are terminated by a `return` statement.

In this case, your `switch` statement prescribes the return value for a specific set of logic paths, but the compiler can't guarantee that the condition will be true. You need to provide a `return` statement (it can be `return null;`) to ensure that a return value is provided should your condition not execute. This is true regardless of the logical construct being used (it's not unique to the `switch` construct).

To use a simple example, the following is not allowed, because the compiler cannot guarantee that a return value will be provided:

```
public static Object retVal(String input) {
    switch on input {
        when 'Test' {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is one way to make it legal, using `when else` to cover any case not already handled by a `when` block:

```
public static Object retVal(String input) {
    switch on input {
        when 'Test' {
            return true;
        }
        when else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

That guarantees that there will be a return value, regardless of the logical path followed and regardless of the input parameter.

Another way to deal with the issue is to place a simple `return` statement after the `switch`. This applies equally to other logical constructs.

```
public static Object retVal(String input) {
    switch on input {
        when 'Test' {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Duh! I can't believe I missed that thought! Thanks for pointing out what should have been obvious to me!  :)